# LaTeX adding 2 logos in the thesis front page

Tags: graphics, templates

How can I add these 2 images ([Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzCZx.png) and [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTpWa.png)) on the right size of my first thesis page. I already have one logo at the top of the page.
I am using a [template](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uC7Fj4W2DtrYLcLLBzR-76KJtVO8YTQQ) and this is the part of the code I am looking at now:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


%% English version
%% MIEEC options

\usepackage[mieec]{feupteses}

%\usepackage[mieec,juri]{feupteses}

%\usepackage[mieec,final]{feupteses}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subfig}

%\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{colortbl}

%% Path to the figures directory

%% TIP: use folder ``figures'' to keep all your figures
\graphicspath{{figures/}}



%% Start of document

\begin{document}

%%----------------------------------------
%% Information about the work
%%----------------------------------------
\title{this is where to put the title of the thesis}
\author{it's me}

%% Uncomment next line for date of submission

\thesisdate{Academic year, 1999 - 1999}

%% Comment next line copyright text if not used

\copyrightnotice{author, 2018}

\supervisor{Supervisor}{blablabla, PhD}

%% Uncomment next line if necessary

\supervisor{Co-supervisors}{blablabla, PhD - blablabla, PhD}

%% Uncomment committee stuff in the final version if used
%\committeetext{Approved by \ldots:}
%\committeemember{Co-supervisor}{blablabla}
%\committeemember{Referee}{Name of the Referee}
%\committeemember{Referee}{Name of the Referee}

%\signature

%% Specify cover logo (in folder ``figures'')

\logo{thisone.pdf}

%\newcommand{\logo}[2][3]{\includegraphics[scale=#1]{#2}}
```

Tell me how can I help you more in order to be more precise. And I'm sorry if I omitted some important feature but I am quite new to LaTeX.

Comment: The answer probably lies in the `feupteses` package which I (we?) don't have. Have you tried using a second `\logo` like `\logo{thatone.pdf}` to go with the first?

Comment: I tried to add it like this but it doesn't work and gives me an error redirecting me to another part.In the template I linked there is the Feupteses package but if you want I can "copy paste" it here..

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look into file `feupteses.sty` you can find the following code to add the defined logo into the title page:

```
\vspace*{35mm}%
\hbox to \textwidth{%
  \setbox\@crestbox=\vbox{\includegraphics[width=72mm]{\@logo}}% <=================
\box\@crestbox%
}
```

Now you can define a second logo with

```
\def\logoa#1{\gdef\@logoa{#1}} % <======================================
```

and then change the code for the inserted logo to

```
\vspace*{35mm}%
\hbox to \textwidth{%
  \setbox\@crestbox=\vbox{\includegraphics[width=72mm]{\@logo}\hfill\includegraphics[width=72mm]{\@logoa}}% <=================
\box\@crestbox%
}
```

The new definition of `maketitle` can be added to your preamble, enclosed with commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. 
With the folowing MWE (important code changings are marked with `<=======`)

```
%% FEUP THESIS STYLE for LaTeX2e
%% how to use feupteses (English version)
%%
%% FEUP, JCL & JCF, 31 July 2012
%%
%% PLEASE send improvements to jlopes at fe.up.pt and to jcf at fe.up.pt
%%

%%========================================
%% Commands: pdflatex tese
%%           bibtex tese
%%           makeindex tese (only if creating an index) 
%%           pdflatex tese
%% Alternative
%%          latexmk -pdf tese.tex
%%========================================

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

%% For iso-8859-1 (latin1), comment next line and uncomment the second line
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

%% English version

%% MIEEC options
\usepackage[mieec]{feupteses}
%\usepackage[mieec,juri]{feupteses}
%\usepackage[mieec,final]{feupteses}


%% Additional options for feupteses.sty:
%% - onpaper: links are not shown (for paper versions)
%% - backrefs: include back references from bibliography to citation  place

%% Uncomment to create an index (at the end of the document)
%\makeindex

%% Path to the figures directory
%% TIP: use folder ``figures'' to keep all your figures
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

%%----------------------------------------
%% TIP: if you want to define more macros, use an external file to keep them
\include{mymacros}
%%----------------------------------------

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\def\logoa#1{\gdef\@logoa{#1}} % <======================================
%% Front pages
\def\maketitle{%
\newbox\@crestbox

%% TITLE page
\begin{titlepage}
{\vspace{-15mm}\Large\bf \textsc{\@school}}

\vspace*{35mm}%
\hbox to \textwidth{%
  \setbox\@crestbox=\vbox{\includegraphics[width=72mm]{\@logo}\hfill\includegraphics[width=72mm]{\@logoa}}% <=================
\box\@crestbox%
}
\vspace*{30mm}%
{\def\baselinestretch{1.2}\Huge\bf \@title \par}
\vskip 10mm%
{\Large\bf \@author}%
\if@watermark
\relax
\else
\vskip 10mm%
{\Large\textsc \@provisionaltext}
\fi
\vfill%
{\large \@degree}%
\vskip 2mm
\unvbox\@supervisorstext
\vskip 10mm
\@thesisdate
\end{titlepage}%

%% copyright page
\ifx\@copyrightnotice\@empty
  \relax
\else
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \par
  \begin{center}
    \@copyrightnotice
  \end{center}
\fi
\clearpage
} % maketitle
\makeatother % <========================================================

%%========================================
%% Start of document
%%========================================
\begin{document}

%%----------------------------------------
%% Information about the work
%%----------------------------------------
\title{Title of the Dissertation}
\author{Name of the Author}

%% Uncomment next line for date of submission
\thesisdate{July 31, 2008}

%% Comment next line copyright text if not used
\copyrightnotice{Name of the Author, 2008}

\supervisor{Supervisor}{Name of the Supervisor}

%% Uncomment next line if necessary
\supervisor{Second Supervisor}{Name of the Supervisor}

%% Uncomment committee stuff in the final version if used
%\committeetext{Approved by \ldots:}
%\committeemember{President}{Name of the President}
%\committeemember{Referee}{Name of the Referee}
%\committeemember{Referee}{Name of the Referee}
%\signature

%% Specify cover logo (in folder ``figures'')
%\logo{uporto-feup.pdf}
\logo{logo.png}
\logoa{logo2.png} % <===================================================

%% Uncomment next line for additional text  below the author's name (front page)

%%----------------------------------------
%% Preliminary materials
%%----------------------------------------

% remove unnecessary \include{} commands
\begin{Prolog}
  \include{abstract} % the abstract
  \include{acknows}  % the acknowledgments
  \include{quote}    % initial quotation if desired
  \cleardoublepage
  \pdfbookmark[0]{Table of Contents}{contents}
  \tableofcontents
  \cleardoublepage
  \pdfbookmark[0]{List of Figures}{figures}
  \listoffigures
  \cleardoublepage
  \pdfbookmark[0]{List of Tables}{tables}
  \listoftables
  \include{abbrevs}  % the list of abbreviations used
\end{Prolog}

%%----------------------------------------
%% Body
%%----------------------------------------
\StartBody

%% TIP: use a separate file for each chapter
\include{chapter1} 
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5} 

%% comment next 2 commands if numbered appendices are not used
\appendix
\include{appendix1}

%%----------------------------------------
%% Final materials
%%----------------------------------------

%% Bibliography
%% Comment the next command if BibTeX file not used
%% bibliography is in ``myrefs.bib''
\PrintBib{myrefs}

%% Index
%% Uncomment next command if index is required
%% don't forget to run ``makeindex thesis'' command
%\PrintIndex

\end{document}
```

you get the following resuling title page:

[image: resulting pdf title page]